# How can I join an XML column back onto the record it originates from?

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a table "Blah" with a PK column BlahID and an XML column BlahItems in a database on SQL Server 2005.

This table has records as follows...

```
BlahID BlahItems
------ ------------------------------------------------------
1      <root><item name="Fred" /><item name="Wilma" /></root>
2      <root><item name="Lisa" /><item name="Bart" /></root>
```

How can I query that table to produce the following....

```
BlahID BlahItem
------ --------
1      Fred
1      Wilma
2      Lisa
2      Bart
```

The closest I've managed to get is on a per record FUNCTION that does something along the lines of the following...

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Blahs(@id int)
RETURNS @list TABLE (BlahID int, BlahItem nvarchar(max))
BEGIN
    DECLARE @xml AS xml
    SELECT @xml = BlahItems FROM dbo.Blah AS b WHERE b.BlahID = @id

    INSERT INTO @list
    SELECT @id, tbl.col.value('@name','nvarchar(max)')
    FROM @xml.nodes('/root/item') tbl(col)
    RETURN
END

SELECT * FROM dbo.Blahs(1)
```

```
BlahID BlahItem
------ --------
1      Fred
1      Wilma
```

My ultimate goal is to create a VIEW of the "expanded" data and then query against the view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this query:

```
SELECT BlahID, XmlItems.BlahItem.value('@name', 'nvarchar(100)') AS BlahItem
FROM Blah CROSS APPLY BlahItems.nodes('/root/item') AS XmlItems(BlahItem)
```

For more info check [this three-part article](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/050803.htm) by Alex Homer.